# successive Joins in Rhino.ETL

Tags: rhino-etl

I have 3 tables i want to join in 1 table.
How can i do that with Rhino.ETL ?

I know how to join 2 tables, but not 3...
Thanks
John

Answer (score 1):

Use a nested join.

Let's say your tables are A, B and C.
First join A and B to get AB.
Then join AB to C.